# Handling data collection from HLK ArchitecturalDesign.FwpmProviders.MaintainIdentifying when running on AWS EC2?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

What's the right way to handle collection of data from the **Filter.Driver.WindowsFilteringPlatform.ArchitecturalDesign.FwpmProviders.MaintainIdentifying** when running HLK on AWS?

Should I not be using AWS?  Do I need to use physical hardware?

The test hit an error collecting data.  I'd like to review the system to search for the files but the test has moved on to a later test case and I can no longer access the system via rdp or wttcmd ping.  I can reboot the system, but then I'm not sure what this means for downstream tests.

```
Failed the Job "REQ - WFP-based products must create and maintain at least 1 identifying FWPM_PROVIDER provider object"     
     Job Failed And Rest of the Tasks Cancelled because Task "ArchitecturalDesign.FwpmProviders.MaintainIdentifying" 
Failed with Failure Action FailAndStop

Cause : Task "ArchitecturalDesign.FwpmProviders.MaintainIdentifying" is Marked Failed From the LogFile

Cause : 
Copying File "C:\hlk\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRun07D368B2-0611-E811-A996-127434B89330\WFPLogo.wtl.trace" Fails 

Cause : 
Cannot Find Pattern "C:\hlk\JobsWorkingDir\Tasks\WTTJobRun07D368B2-0611-E811-A996-127434B89330\WFPLogo.wtl.trace"

Cause : 
Task is Marked Failed as it had non-zero Fail Counts in the LogFile
```

Rebooting seems like my only option.  Probably worth changing system status via HLK manager to manual or debug to prevent the test from continuing upon it.  That is, provided it comes back at all after reboot.

Anyone encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a [forum post on msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcad7de2-6d39-4f4c-94d4-54bddd7e760a/hck-wfplogo-test-fwpmprovidersmaintainidentifying-fails-frequently-but-not-always?forum=wfp), the **provider.displayData.name** and **provider.displayData.description** must be in sync between WFPLogo.info and the driver